# Updated field is null using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, statistics, spi

I am going to calculate SPI values for a field in PyQGIS. I created expression for the standardized the values. Stdev and mean values getting correctly. But after update the layer, the new field is getting null values.

How do I change my code get the values?

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
mean = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Mean, "rain_autumn")
print (mean)
stdev = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StDev, "rain_autumn")
print (stdev)

expression = QgsExpression(f'(rain_autumn-{mean})/{stdev}')
print(expression) 
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))


with edit(layer):
    for (f) in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f["spi"]=expression.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Comment: Maybe `print` the output of `expression.evaluate` ? DO you have some values ?

Comment: I printed it and got this output
**built-in method evaluate of QgsExpression object at 0x0000027604845A60**

Comment: Sorry, I meant expression.evaluate(context), you are printing the function, not the result.

Comment: Yeah It is printed as **"None"**. I can not figureout where is the wrong

Comment: I tried with this **expression = QgsExpression(f'("mean"-{mean[0]})/{stdev[0]}')** its worked. thank you